# RasPi + Arduino Master-Slave Servo issues (Nanpy)

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, servo

For my final project in AP Comp Sci I'm making a robot using a Pi and an Arduino, I've gotten virtually everything working other than the Pi-Arduino interface.

So I have my Arduino and Pi hooked up using nanpy, as instructed by [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QumIhvYtRKQ&t=85s).

I understand for the most part how the coding works, but how would I call this?

```
#include <Servo.h>


Servo servoA;
Servo servoD;
int posA, posD;
```

*The code above is written as if I was programming the Arduino by itself

note - A & D are referring to the WASD scheme I am using to control the Robot

*A & D being keys bound to those servos of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

```
from nanpy import Servo
```

past that I really don't know
and stack hasn't really treated me well on this subject soooooo ima just ask the nanpy dev